# Scheduling of delivery orders to have acceptable inventory levels

Tags: optimization, modeling

I have a problem of scheduling of delivery orders of different products on a month horizon. Such that the stock, which has a consistent inflow from my production, stays always between safe levels. For example I can't make all deliveries on day one because not enough stock, also, I can't schedule it last day because intime my stock will become full and products would be destroyed. Any reference to similar problems or class of problems is appreciated. It is not inventory control since I don't control the stock replenishment, I just want to schedule the distribution of orders.

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?  What have you attempted so far and in what context & language?

Comment: Please explain more about your scenario and question.